# enforce path contraints with fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am getting an error when using regex path contraint in fast api.

```py
ValueError: On field "serial" the following field constraints are set but not enforced: regex. 
For more details see https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#unenforced-field-constraints
```

The function signature looks like this.

```py
@devices.get("/{serial}", response_model=Device)
async def get_serial(serial: int = Path(..., regex=r"(?:\d{18}|\d{24})")) -> dict:
```

The error points me to the pydantic documentation, but I don't understand what's wrong. I believe what they suggest there is exactly what fastapi is supposed to do under the hood.

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#unenforced-field-constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're limiting the field to `int`, you can't apply a `regex` constraint to the field. Instead define the field as `str`, and the regex can be applied as you want:

```
async def get_serial(serial: str = Path(..., regex=r"(?:\d{18}|\d{24})")) -> dict:
```

This is because the `int` constraint takes precedence over the `regex` constraint, and is what the error attempts to convey.